Поправить маштаб иконки SVG
Что та сделала, никак не выходит выровнять маштаб.
Ширина и высота 36, а маштаб должен как я понимаю равен 1
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 36000000 36000000" width="36" height="36"><circle fill="#273b7a" cx="18000000" cy="18000000" r="18000000"/><path fill="#4285f4" d="M18392187 16345311v3450000h5395311a6059374.6 6059374.6 0 0 1-11843749-1796875 6057812 6057812 0 0 1 6056250-6056249c1562500 0 2984375 598437 4057812 1570312l2531250-2709375a9759374.4 9759374.4 0 1 0 3024999 5542187z"/><path fill="#ea4335" d="M17999999 11942187c1562500 0 2984375 598437 4057812 1570312l2531250-2709375a9756249.3 9756249.3 0 0 0-15210936.6 2625000l2978124.6 2385937a6054687.1 6054687.1 0 0 1 5643750-3871874z"/><path fill="#fbbc05" d="M11942187 17999999c0-771875 150000-1507813 414062-2187500l-2978124.6-2382812a9714061.7 9714061.7 0 0 0-1137500 4571874c0 1659375 415624.9 3221874 1146874.9 4590625l2960937.7-2426562a6031249.6 6031249.6 0 0 1-406250-2164063z"/><path fill="#34a853" d="M21367186 23031248a6023437.1 6023437.1 0 0 1-3367187 1026563 6054687.1 6054687.1 0 0 1-5651562-3893750l-2960937.7 2426562A9756249.3 9756249.3 0 0 0 24342186 25412498Z"/><path fill="#4285f4" d="M27759374 17999999c0-564063-53126-1117187-145314-1654688h-9223437v3450000h5395312a6068749.5 6068749.5 0 0 1-2420312 3234375l2974999 2384374a9734374.2 9734374.2 0 0 0 3417189-7414061z"/></svg>



Из вопроса не совсем понятно для чего и где вы это правите, но вашему SVG мешают фиксированные размеры прямо в самом первом теге-обёртке уберите эти height="36" width="36" и будет вам счастье, а именно в том, что размерами можно будет манипулировать не только на уровне стилей, но и размера контейнера. За этот редактор увы не скажу, не знаком, не исключено что их и там можно убрать.

@stylok, там координаты в путях тоже увеличены.

@De.Minov, как я понял из вопроса, а уж Лена умеет поставить в тупик своими формулировками,) она как раз пытается манипулировать размерами, а у неё не выходит. Вот я и указал главную причину, которая мешает полноценной манипуляции чем угодно кроме разумеется viewBox. Да, циферки там забористые, но они погоды не делают, если убрать указанные мною параметры.

Я вообще вопрос не понимаю.

Даже не знаю что тут в ответ написать.
В общем вот, исправленное изображение + оптимизировал.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <circle cx="18" cy="18" r="18" fill="#273b7a"/>
  <path fill="#4285f4" d="M18.4 16.3v3.5h5.4c-1 3.2-4.4 5-7.6 4-2.5-.8-4.3-3.1-4.3-5.8 0-3.3 2.7-6.1 6.1-6.1 1.6 0 3 .6 4.1 1.6l2.5-2.7c-4-3.6-10.1-3.4-13.8.6s-3.4 10.1.6 13.8 10.1 3.4 13.8-.6c2-2.2 2.9-5.3 2.4-8.2h-9.2z"/>
  <path fill="#ea4335" d="M18 11.9c1.6 0 3 .6 4.1 1.6l2.5-2.7c-4-3.6-10.1-3.4-13.8.6-.6.6-1 1.3-1.4 2l3 2.4c.9-2.3 3.1-3.9 5.6-3.9z"/>
  <path fill="#fbbc05" d="M11.9 18c0-.8.1-1.5.4-2.2l-3-2.4c-.7 1.4-1.1 3-1.1 4.6 0 1.7.4 3.2 1.1 4.6l3-2.4c-.2-.7-.4-1.5-.4-2.2z"/>
  <path fill="#34a853" d="M21.4 23c-1 .7-2.2 1-3.4 1-2.5 0-4.8-1.6-5.7-3.9l-3 2.4c2.5 4.8 8.4 6.6 13.2 4 .6-.3 1.2-.7 1.8-1.2L21.4 23z"/>
  <path fill="#4285f4" d="M27.8 18c0-.6-.1-1.1-.1-1.7h-9.2v3.5h5.4c-.4 1.3-1.3 2.5-2.4 3.2l3 2.4c2-1.8 3.3-4.5 3.3-7.4z"/>
</svg>



Там в самих путях есть косяки, но если использовать при таких размерах, то не заметно)
